# Topic mining algorithm in c/c++

Tags: c++, c

I am working on subject extraction fro articles algorithm using c++.
First I have written code to remove words like articles, propositions etc.

Then rest of the words get store in one char array: `char *excluded_string[50] = { 0 };`

```
    while ((NULL != word) && (50 > i)) {
    ch[i] = strdup(word);
    excluded_string[j]=strdup(word);
    word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    skp = BoyerMoore_skip(ch[i], strlen(ch[i]) );
        if(skp != NULL)
        {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
j++;
```

`skp` is NULL when ch[i] is not articles or similar caregory.
This function checks whether any word belongs to articles or propo...etc

Now at the end ex..[] contains set of required words. Now I want occurrence of each words in this array and after that word which has max occurrence. All if more then one.

**What logic should I use?**

What I thought is:
Taking and two dimension array. First column will have word. and 2nd column I can use for storing count values.

Then for each word sending that word to the array and for each occurance of that word increment count values and store that count values for that words in 2nd column.

But this is costly and also complex.

Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to count the occurrences of each word in an array then you can do no better than O(n) (i.e. one pass over the array). However, if you try to store the word counts in a two dimensional array then you must also do a lookup each time to see if the word is already there, and this can quickly become O(n^2).

The trick is to use a hash table to do your lookup. As you step through your word list you increment the right entry in the hash table. Each lookup should be O(1), so it ought to be efficient as long as there are sufficiently many words to offset the complexity of the hashing algorithm and memory usage (i.e. don't bother if you're dealing with less than 10 words, say).

Then, when you're done, you just iterate over the entries in the hash table to find the maximum. In fact, I would probably keep track of that while counting the words so there's no need to do it after ("if thisWordCount is greater than currentMaximumCount then currentMaximum = thisWord").

I believe the standard C++ `unordered_map` type should do what you need. There's an example [here](http://cpptutorials.freeforums.org/tr1-unordered-map-t621.html).

Comment: Moreover, as you seems to need the words with the most occurences, maybe this data should be stored in an ordered way. A _heap_ might be suited for your case (`priority_queue` in STL). Complexity is O(log n) for an insertion, O(1) to get the topmost element and O(log n) to remove an element.

Comment: @ams: I have to deal with big data. The approach I told is now not at all useful due to it's complexity order. What is your suggestion `unordered_map` or what NoWiS told will suffice my requirement or do I need something else?

Comment: @NoWiS: I think while dealing with bigdata first converting it to ordered after initial preprocessing(which itself takes time) is not a good idea..

Comment: On second thought, a heap is not suited at all. The hash table is probably the easiest way and maybe the fastest to do what you want to do. Do you need only the word(s) with the max occurences ? Or do you need all of them to be ordered by the number of their occurences ?

Comment: I believe a hash table is the *only* way to do big data efficiently. I can't speak to how efficient any specific implementation might be though.

Comment: @ams: thanks, can you please point me any good example that uses hash table, probably program or something. I have not used it before. I must see it on web.  But link me if you have specific in mind!

Comment: @NoWiS: No I need words with max occurance only.No need for them to be in order. Just think I have one articles and processing one by one all the words. And at last I want word which is with max occurance. If I could store count values in hash table while processing each first during first iteration then it will be very useful for me. But I still cant figure out how to proceed ...

Comment: I added a link to the answer.